# Rayshader package error for Plotting and Saving 2D and 3D Visualizations in R studio

Tags: r, visualization

For 3D visualizaiton used matrix data. Package: Rayshader 0.34.0.

The data is can be seen in render_camera but using high_quality function facing problem in saving rendeeing out put.

Error in rayrender::obj_model(cache_filename, x = -bbox_center[1], y = -bbox_center[2],  :
unused argument (texture = TRUE)

I was expecting a render image so that my 3d map can be saved in png format with rendering quality.

```
mat |>
  height_shade(texture = textr) |> 
  plot_3d(heightmap = mat,
          zscale = 1000,
          solid = FALSE, 
          shadowdepth = 0)
render_camera(theta = -100, phi = 30, zoom = .7)
render_highquality("E:/URP/R/3D Bangladesh/DATA/Images/tp.png",
  samples = 450,
  preview = FALSE,
  light = TRUE,
  lightdirection = c(135, 45),
  lightcolor = c("white"),
  lightintensity = c(800),
  ambient_light = 0.5,
  shadow_intensity = 0.5,
  zscale = 1,
  width = 8000, height = 8000,
  interactive = FALSE)
```

Answer (score 0):

Install most recent dev versions of rayshader and rayrender.

remotes::install_github("https://github.com/tylermorganwall/rayshader")
remotes::install_github("https://github.com/tylermorganwall/rayrender")

Answer (score 0):

Same issue.
I've tried to install the most recent dev versions but probably I do something wrong.
What do I have to choose here (and later similarly for rayrender)?
[terminal options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/83fL0.png)

If I choose "All" at every steps I get some conflicts

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).